# Combining functions Questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I think I understand this but just want to confirm that I have simplified sufficiently.

Given: 
$$g(x)=\sin^2x$$ $$h(x)=\cot x$$$$f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$$ I am asked to find $f(x)$ and simplify:

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
f(x)& = g(x)-h(x)  \\
 & = \sin^2x-\cot x\\
 &=\dfrac{\sin^2x(\sin x)}{1(\sin x)}-\left(\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)\\
 &=\dfrac{\sin^3x-\cos x}{\sin x}\\
&=\boxed{cscx(\sin^3x-cosx)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Given: $$f(x)=\sin^2x$$$$g(x)=\cot x$$ Determine the equation $\left(\dfrac{f}{g}\right)(x)$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left(\dfrac{f}{g}\right)(x)&=\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cot x}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin^2x}{1}\cdot\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin^3}{\cos x}\\
&=\boxed{\sin^2x\tan x}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: I would prefer simplifying $\tfrac fg$ further by writing it as $\sin^2x\tan x$.

Comment: Oh right, other than that though everything looks fine?

Comment: Yes, though I would recommend writing the first $f(x)$ as $\csc x(\sin^3 x -\cos x)$.

Comment: Your "simplified" version feels more complicated to me than the original version.

Comment: For the ratio question, it is fine, but faster is to note that $\frac{1}{\cot x}=\tan x$.